# Cookies are showing some random values

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I am trying to get integer value of "id" but second parameter of cookie requires string value only. It is not showing me any error but it is printing random values
like "javax.servlet.http.Cookie@821ece4"  while I tried to print it.Any solution to resolve this.

```
@WebServlet("/Delete")
public class Delete extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String s = request.getParameter("id");
        Cookie ck1 = new Cookie("name", s);
        response.addCookie(ck1);

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        pw.print("<html>");
        pw.print("<body>");

        pw.println("<form action = 'index.html' > <input type = 'submit' value = 'Home'></form>");

        pw.print("</html>");
        pw.print("</body>");


        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jeet","root","jeet");
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Delete from jeet where id = ?");
            pst.setInt(1, id);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pw.println("<center>");
            pw.println("<br>");
            pw.println("Your Record is been Deleted");
            pw.println("<br>");

            Cookie ck2[] = request.getCookies();

            pw.println("Your last Record Deleted is " +ck2[1]);
            pw.println("</center>");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `Cookie` has not special `toString()` implementation, that's why the JVM reference is printed. You need to extract the information to print yourself.
Check the available methods to extract the information: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html

Comment: you can cast Int to String

Comment: Building on @HerrDerb s comment, you are probably looking for something like `ck2[1].getValue()` or `ck2[1].getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` and try to print it, you are only going to be getting the object reference, hence the `@821ece4`. What you need to do is actually make use of the `Cookie` methods as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html). Something like:

```
ck[2].getName()
```

to get the name of the cookie or

```
ck[2].getValue()
```

to get the actual stored value.

Answer (score 0):

You should print the `pw.println("Your last Record Deleted is " +ck2[1].getValue());`